# How to create local mirror for Ubuntu inside docker container?

Tags: 14.04, apt, docker, apt-mirror

I want to create local mirror for Ubuntu inside docker container. Here is the [link](https://github.com/ekino/docker-images) that I am following from Git hub.

Now the issue is that it is taking too much time to download the whole packages,even though I divided its in part like main,restricted and universe but it is downloading packages of 22 GB. My system is powered on since last 48 hrs but still it has not been completed. And yes I have a good speed Internet. But I think it goes in an infinite loop and stuck somewhere.

Is there any other way to accomplish this? Any suggestions?

Thank you so much in advance!